Cannot remove OneDrive files shared with links
I'm having a really frustrating problem with shared files in my OneDrive. I'm cleaning up some old files, and there are a few Word documents that I was sent using a link that I can't remove. They appear in a few specific places:

The OneDrive IOS app, in the "Home" tab under "Recent Files." When I open the menu for this, I can go to details, where I can click on a check mark in the top right to remove the file. When I do that, the message "File name might have been removed or deleted, or you might not have permission to edit it" appears.
The Microsoft 365 sidebar on Edge on Windows 11 under "Recent." The only way I can interact with them here is to open them. There aren't any options when I right click.
The "Microsoft 365 (Office)" Desktop app on Windows 11, under "Recently Opened." I can hide them from this list, but this does not remove them, and I can still see them when I filter to view hidden items. This also doesn't hide them from any other location.

I found this question from 2021 that seems to be describing the same issue, but the answer is targeted at the file owner (which I'm not), and it looks like the settings they're describing are no longer accessible anyways. The way one of the responses is worded makes it seem like you could do this in the past, so maybe there's still functionality left over?
I also found this forum and tried the solutions, but they didn't fix the problem either.
Is there a way I can remove, or hide, or do something so I can't see these documents anymore? Or, if there isn't, is there a way I can completely wipe my OneDrive account and start over from scratch without any data?
